# What obstacles and limitations will I face by choosing Linux + Mono + C# + MySQL for a web application?

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, mono

Is this combination possible at all?
If yes, will I still need to buy Visual Studio? Will I be able to use MySQLi via C#?

Thank you.

**Update:** So, does it mean I can use anything from C# ASP.NET (like controls) and it'll work under Mono?

Comment: @z-boss http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET#Limitations.  I hear that Google is all the rage these days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the combination is possible.  Check [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for one potential combination.

Yes, you can access MySQL via C# and no you don't need Visual Studio.  You can write C# for Mono with a few different IDEs which are not VS.  I trust you're capable of googling for MonoDevelop and SharpDevelop.

By the way, [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications) should give you a good starting point on Web Development with the Linux/Mono/C#/MySQL stack.

Comment: +1 - it should be noted that you can write C# with anything - the compiler, csc.exe,  is distributed with the .net framework, and can be freely used.  IDE's basically just use build files that execute it behind the scenes.

Comment: In all fairness intellisense practically justifies itself, but I agree with you in principle.

Comment: @tzenes Good point.  The original questioner can get VS 2008 Shell for free (among other free options) for intellisense support.

Comment: I didn't find anything about C# in the Xampp link.

Comment: @z-boss--getting the Linux/Apache/MySQL stuff going is the tough part.  Getting Mono configured to work with it is relatively easy--hence the link to Xampp.

Comment: VS Shell cannot be used for C# coding, but Visual C# Express edition is already free and available.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are less limited when you choose Linux/Mono than Windows/MS.NET.

With MS.NET you are fixed with key areas like OS and web server, but with mono you can choose almost any Linux (or Unix) distribution and you have more web servers which can run mono web apps (like Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd) compared to dominant IIS on Windows. Also databases (like MySQL, PostgreSQL or NoSQL stuff) runs better and are more supported on Linux machines.

You don't have to buy anything to develop/deploy mono applications (except some hardware). Visual Studio is the best IDE for .NET development, but MonoDevelop is gaining momentum and it's the best choice for Linux.